# Programmatically check if gem in bundle?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

At runtime, after bundler setup is complete, and [groups](http://bundler.io/v1.7/groups.html) are applied, what is the best way to programmatically check if a given `gem_name` is in the bundle?

By reading the source, I've discovered [`Bundler.definition`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler.rb#L152), e.g.

```
gem_name = 'banana'
Bundler.definition.dependencies.map(&:name).include?(gem_name)
```

but unable to find documentation<sup>1</sup>, I don't know if this is the recommended usage.

Update: It looks like `Bundler::Definition#dependencies` returns all dependencies, irrespective of groups.  As an alternative, I've discovered `Bundler::Runtime#dependencies_for` which takes groups as arguments.

```
Bundler.load.dependencies_for(:default, Rails.env).map(&:name).include?(gem_name)
```

However, it seems like a bad idea to duplicate the "group lists" at every call site.  Ideally, I'd like a method in `Bundler` that doesn't require me to specify the current groups.

<sub>1 The bundler website and man page are focused on command-line usage.  I have not found any documentation on the gem's public ruby API.  Comments in the source are helpful, but focused on data types, etc.</sub>

Comment: Even if it's already in the bundle it doesn't mean it's *currently* installed. I don't think you can get away from rescuing LoadError.

Comment: Good point, but let's pretend, for the sake of SCIENCE, that this isn't about LoadError ;)

Comment: You may want to look at the Bundler GraphViz code for drawing, because it shows how an external chunk of code decides what's connected. (This is a guess, not an answer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bundler is used to set up the applications gems, so you can use the `Gem` API rather than `Bundler`:

```
Gem.loaded_specs.has_key? gem_name
```

Bundler will have set things up so that any gems in the bundle (in the appropriate groups) have been activated (so they will have entries in `loaded_specs`) and any other (non-bundle) gems will be prevented from being loaded.

Comment: This is the correct way to check. Bundler does not provide an official public Ruby API at this time.