# How to check from the command line if a gem is in the bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

My question is like [Programmatically check if gem in bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510136/programmatically-check-if-gem-in-bundle) , except that I'm wanting to check from the command line, not from within the program.

I've set up CI with codeship for a Rails project, and one of my tests involves running haml-lint. Today, I got a failure because an old branch of the project that doesn't have haml-lint installed was pushed to the repository. I want to be able to test whether haml-lint is installed, so that I won't try running it if it isn't installed.

I could do

```
bundle exec haml-lint --version
```

or possibly `bundle list` plus some text handling, but I want to know if there's something more concise and intention-revealing.

Comment: `bundle show haml && echo $?` in your shell will return 0 if the gem exists otherwise will return something not zero and you can pass it to `[[ .. ]]`

Comment: @bjhaid can you turn that comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
bundle list | grep haml-lint
```

will work for you. But implementing program code for that is a clear abuse of Rails-way. For avoiding things like that you just better keep Gemfile.lock in your repository and make it fail in case you removed needed gems for some unknown reason. Because how things are handled in Rails and it's why we need CI, to avoid things like that before hitting production. Building additional code to avoid that kill off all bonuses of that.

Comment: The scenario I'm dealing with is not a newer version removing a gem, but a relatively old version that hadn't incorporated the gem in question.

Comment: How exactly that changes anything? You have CI for that. CI worked. Now you asking how to build something that will protect CI from working. Let CI do its job, while you doing yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `gem('haml-lint')` in from the console, or you can grep for a string in the command line with `grep 'haml-lint' Gemfile`.

Comment: I got `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'haml-lint''`. Were you referring to the Rails console? I was asking about doing it from the command line.

Comment: `grep 'haml-lint' Gemfile` (as per my answer) will work from the command line. @sergeymoiseev's solution with piping in the grep command to `bundle list` would also work from the command line.